# Laravel load settings from cache

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I'm using Laravel 5.7, and I'm saving settings in the database.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->only('app_name', 'app_desc', 'company_phone', 'company_address',
        'service_wage', 'kavenegar_api', 'kavenegar_number'
    );

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        Setting::updateOrInsert(
            ['name' => $key],
            ['val' => $value]
        );
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withFlashSuccess("saved");
}
```

I can get settings with the following helper.

```php
if (!function_exists('getSetting')) {
    function getSetting($key)
    {
        return Setting::where('name', $key)->value('val');
    }
}
```

But there is a problem; We are listing all settings and calling getSetting('setting_name') multiple times which is making one query to the database for each call. That’s a lot of queries to get the settings.

I want to use the cache but how can I when the settings are stored in the database? I also save them in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward. Consult [the docs on caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache) for details, but the basic idea is this:

```
function getSetting($key)
{
    return Cache::remember('setting:' . $key, 3600, function() use($key) {
        return Setting::where('name',$key)->value('val');
    });
}
```

You could also cache *all* the settings into a single cache value. Depending on how many of the settings there are and what proportion you use in an average request, that may or may not be a good approach.

Comment: thanks..In this code, if the key is in the cache, it returns the value
If it does not exist, it takes the value from the database
It is true? Or I dont have understood your point @ceejayoz

Comment: I want to change the  cache data when the settings are changed @ceejayoz

Comment: @MojtabaDelshad Yes, that's how it works - again, this is all detailed at length in the docs. You can put `Cache::forget` calls in your update method to clear out the cache when settings are updated (or you could put them in an Eloquent observer).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if (!function_exists('getSetting')) 
{
    function getSetting($key)
    {
        return Setting::where('name', $key)->first()->val;
    }
}
```

And Dont forget to add the **Namespace** `App\Setting`

How does the function Work

For Example if you have the setting named as `app_name` and While You pass the value to the function

```
Setting::where('name', $key)->first()->val;
```

`getSetting('app_name');` it will find the `first record` with the key `app_name` and select the `val` field value from the object and returns it

**UPDATED FOR THE CACHE**

> THIS IS UNTESTED FUNCTION

```
function getSetting($name)
    {
        if (Cache::has('setting_'.$name)) {
            return Cache::get('setting_'.$name);
        }

        $query = Setting::where('name', $key)->first();
        Cache::forever('setting_'.$name, $query->val);
        return $query->val;
    }
```

This Will remember the cache **forever**  and visit the documentation to read about the `cache`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache

And dont forget to add the `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;` in the namespace list

Comment: thanks bro..But my problem was, how to set the settings in cache...@Manojkiran.A